# Can anyone help me figure out what this algorithm does?

Tags: algorithm, math

I have this algorithm here:

```
sumup(int n) {
    int s = ???, k = 0;
    while(k != n) {
        k = s*(2*k-1)*(2*k-1);
        s = k;
    }
    return s;
}
```

And I need to find out what its purpose is. It doesn't even seem to work with most numbers and it just returns `n` again anyway, once its done.
Does anybody have any idea what this algorithm is used for?
I assumed it was for square roots, but it doesn't really seem to work either way.

Comment: It seems the `while` loops is infinite. The values of `s` and `k` do not go beyond `1`. Are you sure this is the correct code?

Comment: no r was unknown, I just assumed it was gonna be 1 initially, since its a multiplacation

Comment: This looks like an enterprise Time Waster.

Comment: I don't think that without the value of `s` it is possible the figure out what the algorithm does.

Comment: what does `int s = ???` mean?

Comment: I'm supposed figure out what goes in there to make the algorithm work for s=k^2, but it was a trap, its supposed to be just s=k=0 forever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the for loop `s` and `k` are equal. Before the next iteration `k != n` is checked. This is equivalent to `s != n`. So the loop runs until `s == n` holds and then `n` is returned. So the function get the input `n`, runs for some time and returns `n` at the end.

The questions are:

1. Does it terminate? Under what conditions?
   Only if `s` and `n` fit together. E.g. if `0 < n < s` holds the algorithm will not terminate.
2. How long does it take, if it terminates?
   `k` is initialized with `0` and becomes the value of `s` after the first iteration. From there it is basically cubed every iteration. Solving `s^(3^x) = n` leads to a complexity of `Θ(log log n)`.